# How can I delete or update an object that has TypeError?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, typeerror

My application created an object with an error, the user inserted a string (I believe) but the field was Decimal.

I know forms would have prevented it but the insertion happened on a post_save decorator and now I can't access the object, update or delete it.

```py
comandas_antecipadas = ComandaAntecipado.objects.all()
comandas_antecipadas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 244, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1009, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 254, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context)
TypeError: argument must be int or float

comandas_antecipadas.count()
11
comandas_antecipadas[9]
<ComandaAntecipado: ComandaAntecipado object (120)>
comandas_antecipadas[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 302, in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1009, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\projetos\barzim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 254, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context)
TypeError: argument must be int or float
```

Comment: you could try deleting the object via the database's sql console. WARNING: do take a backup of the database before trying this. You should also do it to a snapshot of the database in your staging environment before attempting it in production directly.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: It's not possible to store a string in a database column that's declared to be decimal.

Comment: @Barmar it is in a db such as sqlite which does not enforce column types.

Comment: Thank you @AnuvratParashar, I took the backup and deleted it using SQLite Browser, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is happening when you try to display the object in the console. So, don't do that. Just delete it directly:

```
comandas_antecipadas = ComandaAntecipado.objects.all()
comandas_antecipadas[9].delete()
```